# Is it possible "to calculate at what time the user logged into the website" using Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I would like to know at what time the user logged into the website. How to achieve this? I had came across events and custom variables. What to use and what not?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup event to see the hour of day (custom dimension) to determine at what time event occurred.